# Java ignore spaces in user input

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

Basically, I'm making a caesar cipher program which encrypts or decrypts messages that the user enters. However, if the user enters spaces in the messages (e.g Stack Overflow), it will perform the encryption or decryption offset process on the spaces as well as the letters and obviously I don't want it to do that. I want it to ignore the spaces and print them in the encrypted or decrypted message.

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);   
    String plain;
    String encrypted; 
    char chars[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', ' ', 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', ' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', ' ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z', ' '};

    System.out.println("Please enter your message."); 
    plain = myinput.nextLine().toUpperCase(); 
    myinput.close(); 

    char[] plaintext = plain.toCharArray(); 
    if(plain.isEmpty()) { 
            System.out.println("You need to give me a message to encrypt.");
    }

    for(int c = 0;c < plaintext.length;c++) { 
        for(int p = 0 ; p < 105;p++) { 
            if(p <= 100) { 
                if(plaintext[c] == chars[p]) {
                    plaintext[c] = chars[p + offset];
                        break;
                    }  
                }
            else if(plaintext[c] == chars[p]) {
                plaintext[c] = chars[p - 81];
            }
        }
    }
    encrypted = String.valueOf(plaintext);
    return encrypted;
```

Comment: Have you tried testing for the space character inside your loop, and not performing the offset encryption on that character, but instead just adding it straight to the new string as is?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int p = 0 ; p < 105; p++) {
    if (plaintext[p] == ' ') continue;
```

that's all you need to keep spaces untouched, also remove them fom `chars` array

Comment: Exactly, I think that is the easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical problem in your program, First problem of your program is that, there is no check of space ' ', thus the program don't know what to do when a space found, secondly you are adding `palinttext[c]=chars[p+offset]` so whatever it finds in text it adds it to `palintext[p]` including space ' '. So to solve this you need to add a check of space ' ' in your code and to avoid space you need to add another string ( `output` ) to store your required output, I am showing you the modified code:

```
    Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String plain;
    String encrypted;
    char chars[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
            'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W',
            'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
            'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
            'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
            'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q',
            'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ', 'A', 'B',
            'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
            'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ' };

    System.out.println("Please enter your message.");
    plain = myinput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    myinput.close();

    char[] plaintext = plain.toCharArray();
    String output = ""; // adding a new string
    if (plain.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You need to give me a message to encrypt.");
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < plaintext.length; c++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < 105; p++) {
            if (p <= 100) {
                if (plaintext[c] == ' ') {//checking for space
                    break;
                } else if (plaintext[c] == chars[p]) {
                    output += String.valueOf(chars[p]+offset);//storing value
                    break;
                }
            } else if (plaintext[c] == chars[p]) {
                if (plaintext[c] == ' ') {//checking for space
                    break;
                } else {
                    output += String.valueOf(chars[p]-81);//storing value
                }
            }
        }
    }
    encrypted = String.valueOf(output);
    return encrypted;
```